# filter continuous duplicate chars in a string

Tags: c, string, ignore-duplicates

Is there any problems in my code ,or to be improved ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * filterdupchar(char* s,int n){
    char *tmp2 = s ;
    char *tmp =(char*)malloc(n*sizeof(char));
    for(int j=0;j<n/2;j++){
        int i=0,p=0;
        while(i<n){
            *(tmp+p) = s[i];
            if(s[i]==s[i+1])
                i = i+2;
            else
                i++;
            p++;
        }
    s = tmp;
   }
    s = tmp2;
    return tmp;
}
int main(){
     char * str= "bbaaan";
     printf("%s",str);
     printf("\n");
     char * strnew;
     strnew = filterdupchar(str,6);
     printf("%s",strnew);
     return 1;
}
```

The result should be "ban", but it is appended to something disordered character. 
In my func , is it necessary to give tmp2 to s, and do i need to free sth.?

Comment: What was the output? (Also, you need to free `tmp`).

Comment: your code is working perfectly in my system.

Comment: @Purag output:ban+(something confused code), i thought i may not process the end

Comment: It outputted `ban` for me as well. What compiler are you using, what OS, etc?

Comment: windows 64bit, visual studio , and where should i free tmp , or i free(strnew) instead ?

Comment: At last there r only 3 chars , but the tmp have more space , the remained space is filled with sth. else.

Comment: You use the return value in `main`, so you should free it in main.

Comment: @Purag Read the question, the code is not working.

Comment: @Lundin I ran the code and it worked; if the close vote was misplaced it'll expire soon enough anyway. :)

Comment: @Purag You can always withdraw your close vote. The bugs are standard beginner ones, the accepted answer points all of them out, plus some style issues. One should be able to spot those bugs without running the code... Likely the program works on your computer because you are using a debug build which zero-out all variables and so by luck the string happened to appear null terminated on your system.

Comment: @Lundlin I thought I saw an explicit assignment for the null terminator, but I think I was confusing this question with one I had just seen. I probably just got lucky with a zero somewhere in the malloc'd space. Only ran it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**changes**

- only need single loop and lag character to do the filter ( above was unnecessarily complicated )
- need to allocate number of characters + 1 ( for nullchar ) for tmp..
- malloc cast not required
- added nullchar to end of tmp
- main should return 0 on success. otherwise processes consuming this will get confused
- free strnew is required..
- use valgrind if you have any memory doubts
- consecutive calls to print are redundant..

**code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * filterdupchar(char* s,int n)
{
  int from,to; char last;
  char *tmp = malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char));
  from = to = 0;
  last = 0;
  for(from = 0; from < n; from++)
  {
    if(s[from] != last)
    {
      tmp[to] = s[from];
      to++;
    }
    last = s[from];
  }
  tmp[to] = '\0';
  return tmp;
}
int main()
{
  char * str= "bbaaan";
  printf("%s\n",str);
  char * strnew;
  strnew = filterdupchar(str,6);
  printf("%s\n",strnew);
  free(strnew);
  return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
$ valgrind ./test
==11346== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11346== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11346== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11346== Command: ./test
==11346== 
bbaaan
ban
==11346== 
==11346== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11346==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11346==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 7 bytes allocated
==11346== 
==11346== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11346== 
==11346== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
```

**notes**

> always use a memory checker ( like valgrind ) to test for memory leaks